# Dynamically changing Up parent Activity when using ActionBarSherlock

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

I'm using ActionBarSherlock and I need to dynamically change where pressing Up navigates as there a multiple paths to the same Activity.

If I were using [appcompat-v7](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html#v7-appcompat) I could override [`getSupportParentActivityIntent()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBarActivity.html#getSupportParentActivityIntent%28%29) but ActionBarSherlock does not provide this function in any of it's classes.

Are there any recommended ways in ActionBarSherlock to do this?

Comment: there is no reason to use action bar sherlock anymore.  just don't use it!

Comment: Yes, I just realized that after reading [this blog](http://www.grokkingandroid.com/migrating-actionbarsherlock-actionbarcompat/) but I've already got time invested in existing code - so I'd rather know if there is existing solutions working within ABS that does this.